# How to create a sql query get the 2nd to Max result in table?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in snowflake and I want to see the results for the max date and 2nd to Max date. I wrote a query below which gives the results for max date

```
SELECT MAX(FILE_DATE)  "MAX_DATE"
    ,UPPER(RETAIL)  "SHOP"
FROM PRODUCTS
GROUP BY UPPER(RETAIL)
```

the results are something like this

```
MAX_DATE   SHOP
2022-09-27 SHOP1
2022-08-01 SHOP2
```

I am looking for

```
2nd_MAX_DATE MAX_DATE   SHOP
2022-08-27   2022-09-27 SHOP1
2022-07-01   2022-08-01 SHOP2
```

I tried something with where clause WHERE FILE_DATE < ( SELECT MAX(FILE_DATE) FROM "PRODUCTS" GROUP BY UPPER(RETAILER)) but this isn't working

Comment: how many distinct shops in your table?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a cross join.

Here's a full sample roughly altered to your schema using SQL Server syntax.

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
  Id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
  Retail VARCHAR(100), 
  FileDate DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO Products (Id, Retail, FileDate)
VALUES (1, 'shop 1', '2022-09-01'), 
       (2, 'shop 1', '2022-09-01'),
       (3, 'shop 1', '2022-09-01'),
       (4, 'shop 2', '2022-09-01'),
       (5, 'shop 2', '2022-09-01'),
       (6, 'shop 2', '2022-09-30'),
       (7, 'shop 3', '2022-09-01'),
       (8, 'shop 3', '2022-09-01'),
       (9, 'shop 3', '2022-09-20');

SELECT DISTINCT
    MAX(p1.FileDate) "MAX_DATE",
    UPPER(p1.Retail) "SHOP"
FROM Products p1
    CROSS JOIN Products p2
WHERE
    p1.FileDate > p2.FileDate
GROUP BY 
    p1.Retail,
    p2.Retail
```

Output

```
2022-09-30|SHOP 2
2022-09-20|SHOP 3
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want the latest two file_dates for every shop, you can use WINDOW function

```
WITH CTE as(
SELECT FILE_DATE  
    ,UPPER(RETAIL)  "SHOP"
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UPPER(RETAIL) ORDER BY FILE_DATE DESC) rn
FROM PRODUCTS
)
SELECT "SHOP",MIN(FILE_DATE) second_date, MAX(FILE_DATE) first_date
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn < 3 
GROUP BY "SHOP"
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]
create or replace TABLE SNOWPARK_QUICKSTART.TELCO.Products (
ID INT,
FileDate TIMESTAMP,
Retail VARCHAR(16777216)
);

```
INSERT INTO Products (Id, Retail, FileDate)
VALUES (1, 'shop 1', '2022-09-01'), 
   (2, 'shop 1', '2022-09-01'),
   (3, 'shop 1', '2022-09-01'),
   (4, 'shop 2', '2022-09-01'),
   (5, 'shop 2', '2022-09-01'),
   (6, 'shop 2', '2022-09-30'),
   (7, 'shop 3', '2022-09-01'),
   (8, 'shop 3', '2022-09-01'),
   (9, 'shop 3', '2022-09-20');


SELECT RETAIL
      ,FILEDATE
      ,IFF(RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY RETAIL ORDER BY FILEDATE DESC)=2,'SECOND MAX DATE','MAX DATE') DAY_DESC  
FROM 
    Products 
GROUP BY 
    RETAIL,FILEDATE
QUALIFY 
    RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY RETAIL ORDER BY FILEDATE DESC)<3
```

Comment: You could easily PIVOT this to put Max and Second Max dates on the same row.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data provided PeteGo as a CTE:

```
with Products (Id, Retail, FileDate) as 
(
    select * from values
        (1, 'shop 1', '2022-09-01'::date), 
        (2, 'shop 1', '2022-09-01'::date),
        (3, 'shop 1', '2022-09-01'::date),
        (4, 'shop 2', '2022-09-01'::date),
        (5, 'shop 2', '2022-09-01'::date),
        (6, 'shop 2', '2022-09-30'::date),
        (7, 'shop 3', '2022-09-01'::date),
        (8, 'shop 3', '2022-09-01'::date),
        (9, 'shop 3', '2022-09-20'::date)
)
```

you can use the window function [NTH_VALUE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nth_value.html) and then combine with DISTINCT to de-dup:

```
select distinct
    Retail
    ,nth_value(FileDate, 1) over(partition by retail order by filedate desc) as "1st_MAX_DATE"
    ,nth_value(FileDate, 2) over(partition by retail order by filedate desc) as "2nd_MAX_DATE"
from products
```

gives:

| RETAIL | 1st_MAX_DATE | 2nd_MAX_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| shop 1 | 2022-09-01 | 2022-09-01 |
| shop 2 | 2022-09-30 | 2022-09-01 |
| shop 3 | 2022-09-20 | 2022-09-01 |

But you can see the two values of `2022-09-01` for `shop 1` are getting picked.

and can be shown if you also pick the id's:

```
select distinct
    Retail
    ,nth_value(FileDate, 1) over(partition by retail order by filedate, id desc) as "1st_MAX_DATE"
    ,nth_value(FileDate, 2) over(partition by retail order by filedate, id desc) as "2nd_MAX_DATE"
    ,nth_value(id, 1) over(partition by retail order by filedate, id desc) as "1st_id"
    ,nth_value(id, 2) over(partition by retail order by filedate, id desc) as "2nd_id"
from products
```

| RETAIL | 1st_MAX_DATE | 2nd_MAX_DATE | 1st_id | 2nd_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| shop 1 | 2022-09-01 | 2022-09-01 | 3 | 2 |
| shop 2 | 2022-09-01 | 2022-09-01 | 5 | 4 |
| shop 3 | 2022-09-01 | 2022-09-01 | 8 | 7 |

you can therefore de-dup the shops/dates:

```
select distinct
    Retail
    ,nth_value(FileDate, 1) over(partition by retail order by filedate desc) as "1st_MAX_DATE"
    ,nth_value(FileDate, 2) over(partition by retail order by filedate desc) as "2nd_MAX_DATE"
from (
    select distinct Retail, FileDate from products     
)
```

now gives a `null` as I originally expected:

| RETAIL | 1st_MAX_DATE | 2nd_MAX_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| shop 1 | 2022-09-01 | null |
| shop 2 | 2022-09-30 | 2022-09-01 |
| shop 3 | 2022-09-20 | 2022-09-01 |